# Get parent div in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table within a bootstrap panel.
Something like this:

```
  <Panel className='userPanel'>
     <Table/>
  </Panel>
```

Now I need to have a reference to Panel within Table. There can be a lot of tables/panels on one site the same time, so I don't want to use ids to use them with ReactDom.findDOMNode.... What is the best solution for this?

Edit:
I need a reference in the table because I use Facebooks datatable. These tables do have a static width/height so to make them fluid, I need to add a resize handler that checks the width and height of the parent to adjust.

Comment: I would think the best way to do this would to be to pass the reference from the panel to the tables via props.

Comment: why do you need a reference to Panel within Table? if it is to execute a method on the Panel component you can pass it to Table as a prop for example. Please give more details.

Comment: @mguijarr see my edit

Comment: Like @Pavlin said, pass either a reference to the panel via props to the Table, or like I said pass the function that checks for width and height of the parent via a prop, then call this when you need (in `componentDidMount` ?): `this.props.mycheckfunction()`...

Comment: thanks. I'll do this: ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).parentNode. Much easier.

Comment: indeed :) good to know about `.parentNode`

Answer (score 2):

What you are suggesting breaks the way that React encourages you to work. Components should be encapsulated, all the data they need should be passed to them as props. Every time you make calls **out** from a component you invalidate their referential transparency i.e. the output of a component (usually what is rendered) should be the result of the props passed to it.

Having said that, people use React in different ways (it even gives you `setState` to wreak havoc with purity) however, passing the actual DOM node to children is difficult as when they are instantiated their parents' DOM node does not exist.

I dont know the Facebook DataTable API so I can't really suggest a better way of restructuring your app, but it sounds like you just need a dynamic width/height to size the table so pass down a function to get that.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
  }

  getDimensions() {
    // Do some stuff here to return dimensions
    return {
      width: XXX,
      height: XXX
    }
  }

  render() {
    <Parent ref="el">
      <Table getDimension={ this.getDimensions } />
    </Parent>
  }
}
```

You still can't call `this.props.setDimensions` from within `Table:render` but you cant with the `.parentNode` solution anyway so I'm guessing you’re already rendering the table in `componentDidMount` (or later).